# ActiveResource and json root element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, activeresource

In ActiveResource 4.0.0 I need to have explicit "include_root_in_json = true" like this:

```
class Base < ActiveResource::Base
  self.include_root_in_json = true 
end
```

Why this is not default since Rails 4.0.0 need root element for saving objects by default?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Your line as above fixed it, so thanks.